# How to configure WCF client for WS-Security (UsernameToken + Encrypted body SOAP (no signature))

Tags: wcf, ws-security

I need to configure my WCF client for consuming a JAX service with WS-Security
UsernameToken + Timestamp + Encryption BODY Soap message with certificate.

For the request I need a SOAP message as below:

```
<soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
  xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <xenc:EncryptedKey Id="EK-8653216552B106D28F13688042014758"
    xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
      <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
      <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
          <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
              <ds:X509IssuerName>
              CN=joe,OU=joe,O=joe,L=joe,ST=joe,C=US</ds:X509IssuerName>
              <ds:X509SerialNumber>1262035674</ds:X509SerialNumber>
            </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
          </ds:X509Data>
        </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
      <xenc:CipherData><xenc:CipherValue>R14juoEJtNL1F8.........</xenc:CipherValue>
      </xenc:CipherData>
      <xenc:ReferenceList>
        <xenc:DataReference URI="#ED-28" />
      </xenc:ReferenceList>
    </xenc:EncryptedKey>
    <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-27">
      <wsu:Created>2013-05-17T15:23:21.472Z</wsu:Created>
      <wsu:Expires>2013-05-17T18:10:01.472Z</wsu:Expires>
    </wsu:Timestamp>
    <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-26">
      <wsse:Username>test</wsse:Username>
      <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">
      secret</wsse:Password>
      <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">
      avvRRapCKKjmGAeg9bRX/g==</wsse:Nonce>
      <wsu:Created>2013-05-17T15:23:21.472Z</wsu:Created>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
  <xenc:EncryptedData Id="ED-5"
  Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content"
  xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
    <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc" />
    <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKey"
      xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
      xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd">
        <wsse:Reference URI="#EK-1FEEFE8E1D48513E9413690595467661" />
      </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
    <xenc:CipherData>
      <xenc:CipherValue>OuEL9072pqJqoTegnqZvkYBvM+05gpMgkfs0unDiTGM5IQVm...............</xenc:CipherValue>
    </xenc:CipherData>
  </xenc:EncryptedData>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Exists a specific bindig for this configuration or I must create a custom binding (and how configure it..)?
Anybody can help me?
Thanks

Michele

Comment: You should post answer to your question separately, instead of editing it and appending the answer. That way the question can be marked as "resolved" and people can find it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. It's not possible to have Encrypt without Signature, then I modified the WS Axis to have a ws-security action timestamp + UsernameToken + Encrypt + Signature. The WCF client is configured (programmaticaly) as below:

```
/// <summary>
/// Custom bindind. WS-Security: timestamp + usernameToken + encrypted + signature
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Obj custom binding</returns>
private CustomBinding GetCustomHttpBinding()
{
    CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding();
        // Open and Close = 20s 
    binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20);
    binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20);
        // Send and Receive = 300s
    binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
    binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
    // ++ Setting security binding ++
    var userNameToken = new UserNameSecurityTokenParameters();
    userNameToken.InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToRecipient;

    var securityElement = new AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement();

    securityElement.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;
    securityElement.IncludeTimestamp = true;
    securityElement.RecipientTokenParameters = new X509SecurityTokenParameters(X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.IssuerSerial, SecurityTokenInclusionMode.Never);
    securityElement.InitiatorTokenParameters = new X509SecurityTokenParameters(X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.IssuerSerial, SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToRecipient);
    securityElement.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic128Rsa15;
    securityElement.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.Strict;
    securityElement.SetKeyDerivation(false);
    securityElement.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.Signed.Add(userNameToken);
    securityElement.MessageProtectionOrder = MessageProtectionOrder.SignBeforeEncrypt;
    securityElement.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10;
    binding.Elements.Add(securityElement);

    // ++ Setting message encoding binding ++
    var encodingElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
    encodingElement.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap11;
    encodingElement.WriteEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    //encodingElement.MaxReadPoolSize = 50000000;
    //encodingElement.MaxWritePoolSize = 50000000;
    encodingElement.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 50000000;
    encodingElement.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 50000000;

    binding.Elements.Add(encodingElement);

    // ++ Setting https transport binding ++
    var httpsElement = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
        // Messagge buffer size
    httpsElement.MaxBufferSize = 50000000;
    httpsElement.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 50000000;
    httpsElement.MaxBufferPoolSize = 50000000;

        // Others
    httpsElement.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
    binding.Elements.Add(httpsElement);

    return binding;
}
```