# WCF WS-security client A security error was encountered when verifying the message

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, apache-axis, ws-security

I've a java code which uses axis2 to connect to a web service with WS-security enabled.
I'm trying to call the same service with dotnet WCF.

Here is my correctly working axis2.xml client configuration:

```
    <parameter name="OutflowSecurity">
        <action>
            <items>Timestamp UsernameToken Encrypt Signature</items>
            <user>MyUser</user>
            <passwordCallbackClass>tr.com.mypackage.PWCBHandler</passwordCallbackClass>
            <signaturePropFile>crypto.properties</signaturePropFile>  
            <signatureKeyIdentifier>IssuerSerial</signatureKeyIdentifier>
        </action>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="InflowSecurity">
        <action>
            <items>Timestamp Encrypt Signature</items>
            <user>MyUser</user>
            <passwordCallbackClass>tr.com.mypackage.PWCBHandler</passwordCallbackClass>
            <signaturePropFile>crypto.properties</signaturePropFile>  
            <signatureKeyIdentifier>IssuerSerial</signatureKeyIdentifier>
        </action>
    </parameter>
```

Here is the correct soap envelope java axis2 produces (I've changed private data):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
      <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="SIG-5">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
          <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
            <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="soapenv" />
          </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
          <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
          <ds:Reference URI="#id-4">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="" />
              </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <ds:DigestValue>SOME ENCRYPTED VALUE</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>
          SOME ENCRYPTED VALUE
        </ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-SOMEVALUE">
          <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-SOMEVALUE">
            <ds:X509Data>
              <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                <ds:X509IssuerName>C=XY,O=ORG,CN=Test ORGN ASD NA</ds:X509IssuerName>
                <ds:X509SerialNumber>SOMENUMBER</ds:X509SerialNumber>
              </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
            </ds:X509Data>
          </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
      </ds:Signature>
      <xenc:EncryptedKey xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Id="EK-SOMEVALUE">
        <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
        <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
          <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            <ds:X509Data>
              <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                <ds:X509IssuerName>C=XY,O=ORG,CN=Test ORGN ASD NA</ds:X509IssuerName>
                <ds:X509SerialNumber>SOMENUMBER</ds:X509SerialNumber>
              </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
            </ds:X509Data>
          </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
        <xenc:CipherData>
          <xenc:CipherValue>SOMEVALUE</xenc:CipherValue>
        </xenc:CipherData>
        <xenc:ReferenceList>
          <xenc:DataReference URI="#ED-3" />
        </xenc:ReferenceList>
      </xenc:EncryptedKey>
      <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-2">
        <wsse:Username>MyUser</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">SOMEVALUE</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">SOMEVALUE</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created>2020-05-21T10:36:25.308Z</wsu:Created>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
      <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-1">
        <wsu:Created>2020-05-21T10:36:25.306Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2020-05-21T10:41:25.306Z</wsu:Expires>
      </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-4">
    <xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Id="ED-3" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content">
      <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc" />
      <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
                                     xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd"
                                     wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKey">
          <wsse:Reference URI="#EK-SOMEVALUE" />
        </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
      <xenc:CipherData>
        <xenc:CipherValue>SOMEVALUE</xenc:CipherValue>
      </xenc:CipherData>
    </xenc:EncryptedData>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I tried the binding specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718621/how-to-configure-wcf-client-for-ws-security-usernametoken-encrypted-body-soap)

This is the envelope I get in C# eventually:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
            xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <u:Timestamp u:Id="uuid-SOMEVALUE-1">
        <u:Created>2020-05-21T11:08:16.280Z</u:Created>
        <u:Expires>2020-05-21T11:13:16.280Z</u:Expires>
      </u:Timestamp>
      <o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-078efc57-eea8-4dcd-9600-1b46d410feb7-3" 
                             ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" 
                             EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">
        SOMEVALUE
      </o:BinarySecurityToken>
      <e:EncryptedKey Id="_0" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p">
          <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
        </e:EncryptionMethod>
        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
          <o:SecurityTokenReference>
            <X509Data>
              <X509IssuerSerial>
                <X509IssuerName>C=XY,O=ORG,CN=Test ORGN ASD NA</X509IssuerName>
                <X509SerialNumber>SOMENUMBER</X509SerialNumber>
              </X509IssuerSerial>
            </X509Data>
          </o:SecurityTokenReference>
        </KeyInfo>
        <e:CipherData>
          <e:CipherValue>SOMEVALUE</e:CipherValue>
        </e:CipherData>
        <e:ReferenceList>
          <e:DataReference URI="#_2"/>
        </e:ReferenceList>
      </e:EncryptedKey>
      <o:UsernameToken u:Id="SOMEVALUE-1">
        <o:Username>MyUser</o:Username>
        <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">CLEAR TEXT PASSWORD</o:Password>
      </o:UsernameToken>
      <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
          <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
          <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
          <Reference URI="#_1">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <DigestValue>SOMEVALUE=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
          <Reference URI="#uuid-SOMEVALUE-1">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <DigestValue>SOMEVALUE</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
          <Reference URI="#uuid-SOMEVALUE-1">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <DigestValue>SOMEVALUE</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>SOMEVALUE</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
          <o:SecurityTokenReference>
            <o:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#uuid-SOMEVALUE-3"/>
          </o:SecurityTokenReference>
        </KeyInfo>
      </Signature>
    </o:Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body u:Id="_1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <e:EncryptedData Id="_2" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
      <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/>
      <e:CipherData>
        <e:CipherValue>SOMEVALUE</e:CipherValue>
      </e:CipherData>
    </e:EncryptedData>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The differences I see:

1. My envelope has BinarySecurityToken Axis2 envelope doesn't.
2. My usernametoken password is plain text. Java has Nonce and created values.
   I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25776403/wcf-create-usernametoken-with-timestamp-and-password-digest-for-oasis-200401-w) but I got System.InvalidOperationException: 'Text cannot be written outside the root element.' error. I added Usernametoken on beforesendrequest, My envelope had two security headers and failed again.
3. My body encrypteddata doesn't have KeyInfo, axis2 envolope has.

What should I look at? I'm kind of stuck here. Any suggestions appreciated.